# Check if user is logged in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to get the userName information if they're logged in.  If user is not logged in, the if statement should skip this action.  I thought implies is what i should be using but its currently throwing me null pointer when user is not logged in.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayHomePage(Model model, Principal user) {
    if(!user.implies(null)){
        String name = user.getName();
        User currentUser = userService.getUserByName(name);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Principal` parameter variable will be `null` if the user is not logged in, so check it for null like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayHomePage(Model model, Principal user) {
    if (user != null) {
        String name = user.getName();
        // ...
```